# Display image instead of text for UIBarButton within StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm creating a ViewController with a Navigation bar. In this bar I add a UIBarButton, on which I will attach a segue to go to another ViewController.
I would like this button to be an image instead of simply text, so I tried to go on the **Attributes Inspector** section and an image to my button. The result is awful:
[image]

As you may think at this point, I would like to have a correct image (like a litlle bit smaller, mine is under xcassets, 25px height and width).

I managed to have something better programmatically, by using this :

```
hpSettingsBtn.image = UIImage(named: "settings")
```

But still not what I would like.

Any idea?

I also tried with a function to use a custom view, but then my button is no more clickable.

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var hpSettingsBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = createSettingsBtn()
        hpSettingsBtn.customView = button
    }

    func createSettingsBtn() -> UIButton {
        //create a new button
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        //set image for button
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings"), for: .normal)
        //set frame
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)

        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        return button
    }
```

And if I use this code, without the UIBarButton (by creating it inside my code and attaching it to the navigation bar myself) then I don't know if it's possible to use the segue with (since the button does not appear on the storyboard).

Comment: I would make an outlet for the button in its parent controller. When that controller did load, you can call self.button.setImage( _:, _:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a segue from first viewController to second viewController and set an identifier to that segue.

```
eg : segue1 //segue identifier
```

then create the custom button

```
func makeSettingsBtn() {
    //create a new button
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings"), for: .normal)
    //set frame
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)

    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    //Add target
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

Button action method

```
@objc func btnClick(_ sender:UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue1", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even if I still don't understand why I can't use the image through the storyboard, this is doing what I want.

Comment: The problem appears because from ios 11 UIBarButtonItem uses autolayout instead of dealing with frames.
Thats why
you should add width constraint for this image-button if you use Xcode 9.

(That is widthAnchor and heightAnchor)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the image inset in storyboard for bar item by going to the ruler looking tab in storyboard, as shown in the image. I hope this helps[image: 1]]

Comment: I tried this but nothing really good happened. I just saw my image being enlarged or even disapearing.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. What values did you fill in for which inputs?

Comment: I tried different ones, mainly using left and right (of course), going with values between 0 to 20, and testing then with 50- 100 - 200, ... I have my image at the center of a "virtual" (I guess) rectangle that take a large place, and I'm unable to shorten this (my image does not contain this rectangle).